# Rewrite existing file request to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php framework on a shared hosting and this is my directory structure:

```
root (can't change because of shared hosting; here's the .htaccess)
  vendor
  web (index.php, assets in subfolders like css, images or js)
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the framework routing works, but I want Apache to search all existing files (`${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`) only in the web folder, not from the root level.

Example:

http://www.domain.tld/hello/world (virtual path) is rewritten to index.php

http://www.domain.tld/css/bootstrap.css is not found, because the file is in the web/css folder.

http://www.domain.tld/web/css/bootstrap.css would match, because of the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Is it possible to combine `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` with a folder rewrite for existing files only? All other request must be rewritten to the index.php

All in all I want it similar as setting the VirtualHost->DocumentRoot to the web folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^/?$ web/index.php [L]

   # if file is found in web/ folder then route it
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web/$1 -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ web/$1 [L]

   # otherwise route it to web/index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did work except requesting the root path: http://www.domain.tld shows the content of the root directory.